# @Indexed not working with spring data cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra, indexed

I am trying to use `@Indexed` for creating a secondary index on the field using spring data cassandra. But while querying on the field it is throwing exception ***No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators:***

Model:

```
 @Indexed(value = "bar")
 private String bar;
```

Query:

```
@Query("select * from foo where bar = ?0 allow filtering")
```

Comment: same issue, any news?

Comment: I went through a datastax video and got that @Indexed is yet to be supported. Temporary workaround is creating an index by writing a query.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue that was recently fixed

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-213

Looks like upgrading to the latest version will get you the functionality you are looking for.